# Newman's "proof" that surface groups are LERF?

Tags: group-theory, surfaces, geometric-group-theory

In trying to find alternatives to [Scott's paper](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s2-17/3/555/903467?redirectedFrom=PDF), I came across Tretkoff **Covering Spaces, Subgroup Separability, and the Generalized M. Hall Property**, which references [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256045503) of Newman to show surface groups are [LERF](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/LERF_group).

But I don't see how that paper proves it.  The main pertinent result of Newman's paper is that for a closed orientable surface of genus $2$, $\pi_1(S)$ embeds in $SL(8,\mathbb{Z})$.

Newman says the results of Scott's paper follow from the following theorem (which I have paraphrased):

> Let $F=\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}\subset \pi_1(S)$, and suppose $b\in\pi_1(S)$ is such that $ba_i\neq a_ib$ for $1\le i\le k$. Then there is a finite index subgroup $H\le \pi_1(S)$ with $b\in H$ but $F\cap H=\emptyset$.

But how does this show $\pi_1(S)$ is LERF? Isn't the conclusion in the wrong direction? By that I mean that LERF would follow if $F\subset H$ and $b\not\in H$.  The result as stated seems to only show self-centralizing cyclic subgroups are separable.

Comment: I don't see any such claim in Newman's paper. I'd need to see Tretkoff's paper...

Comment: @YCor: Newman's paper contains the line "Scott contains a proof of theorem 2 for surface groups". Since theorem 2 says that self-centralizing subgroups are separable, and Scott doesn't explicitly prove that, it does seem weird to state it that way. But Tretkoff's paper just says surface groups are LERF, and points to Scott, Newman, or Burns,Brunner,Solitar for a proof.

Comment: @YCor: I should add that it is entirely possible Newman does not prove this, but I just wanted to make sure I wasnt missing something.

Comment: If "self-centralizing" means "equal to its own centralizer", it is trivial that every self-centralizing subgroup of a residually finite group is separable (= closed in the profinite topology). Because the centralizer of any subset in a Hausdorff topological group, is closed.

Comment: @YCor: but then what exactly is Newman's paper showing? That these groups are linear?

Comment: He's showing what he stated...